# Why are my mom's contacts on my iPhone?

Tags: icloud, contacts

Why are my mom's contacts on my phone, and how do I delete them?

We have different iCloud accounts and different phone numbers and different email addresses.

I need help on how to remove them from my phone without deleting them from her phone

Comment: As long as you aren't logged in into the same account or use any other method of contact sharing, deleting them should work. Why don't you just delete one of these contacts from your phone and check whether it does get deleted on her phone or not?

Answer (score 4):

It appears if your device was previously used with you mom's iCloud account, and her contact information was not removed from the device before you signed in with your iCloud account. This will merge the contact data from both accounts.

Unfortunately, there is no way to automatically detect which contacts were yours or which ones were your mom's.

A simple solution is to manually delete all the contacts that do not belong to you. First, ensure that your phone is using your account for contacts, otherwise you will be deleting your mom's contacts on her iCloud account. Go to **Settings > `Your Name` > iCloud > Contacts** and check if **Contacts** is on and the account is yours. Then, open the contacts app and tap **edit** on the contact you would like to delete. Finally, scroll to the bottom and press **Delete Contact** then **Delete Contact** on the popup again.

If you happen to use Time Machine on a separate macOS device and use iCloud sync, you could try to recover your old contacts list, delete all your contacts, then re-import the original contacts from the Time Machine backup.

To prevent this from happening in the future (as I have done this many times myself on accident), make sure you completely erase your device before signing in with a new iCloud account.